# Why is my entire smoke domain white

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fire

Im trying to make the sun, however when trying to give it flares my entire smoke domain turns like this [image]

[image]

I'm also using Eevee as a rendering engine

Edit: [image]
and this is baked

Comment: I can edit in the blend file if you want

Comment: Is the simulation baked?

Comment: probably easier to upload simplified blend with issue via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ volumetric sim is missing BTW why do you use two overlaped domains?

Comment: The simulation is baked, and I'm trying to have the sun explode into a super nova

Comment: The value for emission might be too high.

Comment: @no-can-do , turning down the emission just turns the color down, just makes everything more red

Comment: @vklidu , What is volumetric sim, and I have the overlapped domains because of 2 different fire/smoke effects

Comment: @EricXue Yes, the simulation is baked

Comment: have you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

The color is comming from Flames Color Ramp. The last color (left side) of ColorRamp has to be Black to get Transparency in Domain.

[image]

Also you have disabled Sphere from calculation. To let it participate as Inflow you have to click on Monitor icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put the "fac" value of the flame attribute into the strength of emission shader. You can change the emission intensity by multiply the "fac" value.

[image: Shader Editor]